# Failed to apply plugin 'com.android.internal.version-check'

Tags: flutter

Im getting this error while running flutter app

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
[   +6 ms] * Where:
[        ] Build file 'F:\flutterdev\apps\calendar\android\app\build.gradle' line: 24
[        ] * What went wrong:
[        ] A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
[        ] > Failed to apply plugin 'com.android.internal.version-check'.
[        ]    > Could not create plugin of type 'VersionCheckPlugin'.
[        ]       > Could not generate a decorated class for type VersionCheckPlugin.
[        ]          > Lcom/android/ide/common/repository/GradleVersion;
```

its good until I reinstalled visual studio code

does it have anything to do with it?

thanks for your help in future.

Answer (score 3):

Try to upgrading gradle  please make change in following floders-

In **android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties** folder:

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.0.2-all.zip
```

and in **android/build.gradle** folder:

```
classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.1"
```